# Give each Popper its own css style

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a componet that creates 6 experiences each one with its own popper. I want to edit the popper's so that each popper has its each style (background and possition) and I want them all to have the same size image. 
I have tried edditing the paper style and adding a className with the id of each experience as the className property but cannot get any styles I apply to work.

This is my experience compoenent.

```
    import React, { memo, useCallback } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import Popper from '@material-ui/core/Popper';
import gastronomia from 'assets/experiences/gastronomia.jpg';
import productos from 'assets/experiences/productos.jpg';
import giftcard from 'assets/experiences/giftcard.jpg';
import diversion from 'assets/experiences/diversion.jpg';
import deporte from 'assets/experiences/deporte.jpg';
import belleza from 'assets/experiences/belleza.jpg';
import gastronomiaExperiences from 'data/gastronomia';
import productosExperiences from 'data/productos';
import giftcardExperiences from 'data/giftcard';
import diversionExperiences from 'data/diversion';
import deporteExperiences from 'data/deporte';
import bellezaExperiences from 'data/belleza';


// Proptypes definitions to the component.
const propTypes = {
  /** Custom root className. */
  className: PropTypes.string,

};

// Default props definitions.
const defaultProps = {
  className: null,
};

// Component's styles
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'block',
    margin: '0 auto',
    maxWidth: '50%',
    [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
      maxWidth: '70%',
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
      maxWidth: '100%',
    },
    '& .experiences-column': {
      display: 'inline-block',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      textAlign: 'center',
      '&.col1': {
        width: '36.31%',
        [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
          width: 'initial',
        },
      },
      '&.col2': {
        width: '63.69%',
        [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
          width: 'initial',
        },
      },
      '& .experience': {
        padding: 2,
        position: 'relative',
        '& img': {
          width: '100%',
          display: 'block',
        },
        '& .experience-title': {
          position: 'absolute',
          bottom: 30,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          textAlign: 'center',
        },
'& .deporte': {
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        '& img': {
          width: '30px',
          display: 'block',
        },
   },        
      },

paper: {
    border: '1px solid',
    padding: theme.spacing(1)

  },
    },
  },
}), { name: 'ExperiencesStyle' });


/**
 * Component used to render a grid of experiences.
 *
 * @param {object} props - The component's props.
 * @returns {object} React element.
 */
const Experiences = memo(
  (props) => {
    const { className } = props;
    const classes = useStyles(props);

    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

    const handleClick = (event) => {
      setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };

    const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

    const experience = (img, title, id, popoverCategory) => (
      <div
        className="experience"
        aria-describedby={id}
        id={id}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        <img
          data-sizes="auto"
          className="lazyload"
          data-src={img}
          alt={title}
        />
        <div className="experience-title">
          <Typography
            color="textSecondary"
            variant="subtitle2"
            className="highlight highlight1"
            display="inline"
          >
            { title }
          </Typography>
        </div>

         <Popper
          id={id}
          open={anchorEl && anchorEl.id === id || false}
          anchorEl={anchorEl}
          className={id}
        >
          <div className={[classes.paper, id]}>
            {
              popoverCategory.map(url => (
              <Grid 
              sm={4}
              >
                <img
                  key={id}
                  data-sizes="auto"
                  className="lazyload"
                  src={url}
                  alt={ title }
                />
              </Grid>
              ))
            }
          </div>
        </Popper>
      </div>

    );

    console.log();
    return (

      <div className={clsx(classes.root, className)}>
        <div className="experiences-column col1">
          {experience(gastronomia, 'GASTRONOMÍA', 'gastronomia', gastronomiaExperiences)}
          {experience(giftcard, 'GIFT CARD', 'giftcard', giftcardExperiences)}
          {experience(deporte, 'DEPORTE', 'deporte', deporteExperiences)}
        </div>
        <div className="experiences-column col2">
          {experience(productos, 'PRODUCTOS', 'productos', productosExperiences)}
          {experience(diversion, 'DIVERSIÓN', 'diversion', diversionExperiences)}
          {experience(belleza, 'BELLEZA', 'belleza', bellezaExperiences)}
        </div>
      </div>

    );
  },
);

// Component proptypes.
Experiences.propTypes = propTypes;

// Component default props.
Experiences.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default Experiences;
```

I am new to meterial ui and relatively new to react so I am a bit lost on how to get the styles to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code only applies when there is the deporte class is inside a paper class.

```
paper: {
    border: '1px solid',
    padding: theme.spacing(1)},

   '& .deporte': {
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        '& img': {
          width: '30px',
          display: 'block',
        },
   },
```

You can take it out of the paper component in the style and put it in the root.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'block',
    margin: '0 auto',
    maxWidth: '50%',
    [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
      maxWidth: '70%',
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
      maxWidth: '100%',
    },
    '& .experiences-column': {
      display: 'inline-block',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      textAlign: 'center',
      '&.col1': {
        width: '36.31%',
        [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
          width: 'initial',
        },
      },
      '&.col2': {
        width: '63.69%',
        [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
          width: 'initial',
        },
      },
      '& .experience': {
        padding: 2,
        position: 'relative',
        '& img': {
          width: '100%',
          display: 'block',
        },
        '& .experience-title': {
          position: 'absolute',
          bottom: 30,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          textAlign: 'center',
        },
      },
    },
  },
deporte: {
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        '& img': {
          width: '30px',
          display: 'block',
        },
   },
paper: {
    border: '1px solid',
    padding: theme.spacing(1),
},        

}), { name: 'ExperiencesStyle' });
```

Also replace this:

```
<Popper
         id={id}
         open={anchorEl && anchorEl.id === id || false}
         anchorEl={anchorEl}
         className={id}
       >
         <div className={classes.paper}>
           {
             popoverCategory.map(url => (
             <Grid 
             sm={4}
             >
               <img
                 key={id}
                 data-sizes="auto"
                 className="lazyload"
                 src={url}
                 alt={ title }
               />
             </Grid>
             ))
           }
         </div>
       </Popper>
```

with this:

```
 <Popper
          id={id}
          open={anchorEl && anchorEl.id === id || false}
          anchorEl={anchorEl}
          className={id}
        >
          <div className={clsx(classes.paper, classes[id])}>
            {
              popoverCategory.map(url => (
              <Grid 
              sm={4}
              >
                <img
                  key={id}
                  data-sizes="auto"
                  className="lazyload"
                  src={url}
                  alt={ title }
                />
              </Grid>
              ))
            }
          </div>
        </Popper>
```

Comment: No it didnt work updated my question with my latest code.